# What is Thorin's hair colour?

Tags: the-hobbit, tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

I read through "The Hobbit" book trying to find something about Thorin's hair, but I didn't see anything. Has anybody noticed something I haven't?

Comment: Seeing as he was about 200 years old - White?

Comment: @E.T. That's how I imagine him, but Dwalin is only 30 years younger, and has a blue beard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only direct reference to Dwarven hair colour I'm aware of in any of Tolkien's writing (aside from occasional references to blue beards) is the name of one of the seven clans of Dwarves: the Blacklocks (source: Of Dwarves and Men, HoME 12), by which we may assume that this clan is dark-haired.

The seven clans appear to be named after distinguishing physical features: Firebeards (possibly implying red hair), Broadbeams, Longbeards, Ironfists, Stiffbeards, Blacklocks and Stonefoots (same source).  Since Thorin was of Durin's folk, which makes him a Longbeard, and if the conjecture that having black hair (and possibly red) was significant enough for a clan name holds good, then we can conclude that whatever his colour was, it was not black (and possibly not red either).

Comment: That answer looks very good, (+1) and shows some research. If I don't get an answer with more definitive information, this certainly deserves the bounty bonus.

Comment: Interestingly, if hair colour was significant enough for two clans to have distinctive names on account of it, it implies that the other clans all had the same colour. We know that Dwalin has a blue beard, so by that theory Thorin's hair is blue! However Fili & Kili have yellow beards... So the theory doesn't hold.

Comment: I think we can ignore that sort of stuff in the hobbit, since Tolkien himself regretted making it so childish and silly in places.